# How to make a paintComponent follow your mouse?

Tags: java, graphics2d, mousemotionlistener

The following is what I have, I have a paintComponent method in one class,

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g2.setPaint(Color.red);
        g2.fillRect(100, 100, 50, 50);
}
```

I want to make that graphics object(above) follow my mouse in a second class, but I do not know how to call it in my second class(below), I wrote an constructor of the first class, but I don't know how to make it show up on my frame. P.S.
I added mouseMotionListener to my frame

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    GOLDraw g1 = new GOLDraw();//default constructor from the first class
    repaint();
}
```

Please explain in simple terms on how to call the paintComponent method, and why(I'll try to understand it, I don't know much about inheritances and such). Probably because I'm a beginner and I'm doing this wrong, I found nothing after hours of reading the api and google.

```
public class GolPresets extends JComponent implements MouseMotionListener{  


    public GolPresets() {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    Point point;
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){
       point = e.getPoint();
    }


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.drawRect(point.x, point.y, 100, 100);
    }

    public void GUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.add(new GolPresets());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new GolPresets());
        frame.addMouseMotionListener(this);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GolPresets g = new GolPresets();
        g.GUI();
    }

}
```

Comment: Calling `repaint` will schedule a "paint" event on the Event Dispatching Thread, which will, through a series of additional method calls, call your `paintComponent` method.  See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works

Comment: Here's how to make a Component draggable: http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/drag/Draggable.java

Comment: So far, you've provided a bunch of out of context code, which doesn't provide as with any clues as to what you are doing or how your problem is generated. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
Point lastCursorPoint;

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    lastCursorPoint = e.getPoint();
    repaint();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if (lastCursorPoint != null) {
        g2.setPaint(Color.red);
        g2.fillRect(lastCursorPoint.x, lastCursorPoint.y, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, where does the shared state live? You will need to keep track of the cursor position in your `mouseMoved` method; you should just reuse the already-created component (not a new one every time) and invoke the `repaint()` method on that.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you meant by shared state. I know I need to keep track of the mouse position and paint where my mouse is, but I do not know how to call the paintComponent method, that is the problem.

Comment: In general terms, shared state is mutable state (fields, variables, objects, whatever) that is shared across two or more components (usually classes in Java). In your case, what is your shared state? The location of the mouse. Given that the signature of method `paintComponent` is fixed and proscribed by Swing, you will not be able to pass it as a parameter. The other ways to access that information is either via public static fields in some other class (big no-no), or from one or more fields in the component that is getting painted.

Comment: I used a Point variable, and after edits, in my paintComponent I did         g2.fillRect(point.x, point.y, 50, 50);, but it still doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Well, update your post with your code, and let's see.

Comment: Also, your paintComponent method should call `super.paintComponent(g)` as its first statement.

Comment: @fred I updated my code but it is still not working, the rectangle straight up doesn't show, and it prints out an error message on the console window.

Comment: Add a `repaint()` call in your `mouseMoved` method.

Comment: @Tassos I tried that but that didn't fix my problem, still nothing shows up

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MouseFollower extends JPanel {

   protected Point spot;

   public MouseFollower() {
      final MouseFollower me = this;
      addMouseMotionListener( new MouseMotionAdapter() {
         @Override
         public void mouseMoved( MouseEvent e ) {
            spot = e.getPoint();
            repaint();
         }
      } );

      addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {
         @Override
         public void mouseExited( MouseEvent e ) {
            spot = null;
            repaint();
         }
      } );

      setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 300, 300 ) );
   }

   @Override
   public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
      super.paintComponent( g );
      if ( spot != null ) {
         Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
         g2.setColor( Color.red );
         g2.fillRect( spot.x, spot.y, 50, 50 );
      }
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            JFrame win = new JFrame( "MouseFollower" );
            final MouseFollower mf = new MouseFollower();
            win.add( mf );
            win.pack();
            win.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() {
               @Override
               public void windowClosing( WindowEvent arg0 ) {
                  System.exit( 0 );
               }
            } );

            win.setVisible( true );
         }
      } );
   }
}
```